# how to pass result of $.get to return of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have trouble with the callback of jquery $.get() ajax function.

I'm using the DataTables plugin and trying the "expanding row to see children details" example (can be seen here https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

The problem is this line:
row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
the function format() renders html direct rom the front end as can be seen:

```
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Full name:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
        '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
}
```

It uses data that is already on the table, and the DataTables has no example on how to do it the "server-side" way.

Here i use ajax as jquery deferred object, i need the format() to return the foo() result but it's not happening.

```
function foo(value)
{
    return $.get("<?php echo base_url()?>token/show?id="+value,null);
}


function format (id,callback) 
{
    callback(id).done(function(result) 
    {
         //I need the result to be returned but somehow it's broken
         return result;
     }).fail(function() 
     {
        alert('ajax error');
    });
}
```

It doesnt return the result, but if i do a console log it prints the entire view without any problem.

Here is where i call the function

```
var td = ('td :first-child',$(this))[0];
var id = $('div',td).attr('id');
oTable.fnOpen( nTr, format(id,foo), 'well hiddenRow' );
```

Is there a way using callbacks? or it's not possible? 
Regards

Comment: Why not place `oTable.fnOpen` inside of the `done` callback?

Comment: @Alfonso Garnett this is good, i really appreciate it, but i have similar issues going on another scripts that your answer could not apply for. Not that this answer isn't useful but Roamer gave an answer that really clarify the nature of promises. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data fetcher `foo()` returns a promise. Whatever you do with the data can only be done when the data has arrived and the promise resolved.

The problem with your attempt is that, as written, `format()` returns `undefined` and *cannot* be made to return the `result` you want. That's the nature of asynchronism. The best available would be to return the promise returned by `foo()`, however that's no good to you because (as you know) you want a result, not a promise-of-a-result in your `oTable.fnOpen(...)` call.

The solution is to turn the whole expression inside-out with the asynchronous `foo(...)` on the outide, and `oTable.fnOpen(...)` on the inside.

In its simplest form, the code would be :

```
foo(id).then(function(result) {
    return oTable.fnOpen(nTr, result, 'well hiddenRow');
});
```

But you should also include some error handling :

```
foo(id).then(function(result) {
    return oTable.fnOpen(nTr, result, 'well hiddenRow');
}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return errorThrown;
});
```

And, assuming this code is itself inside some outer function, then you should return the promise generated by the entire chain.

```
function open(id, nTr) {
    return foo(id).then(function(result) {
        return oTable.fnOpen(nTr, result, 'well hiddenRow');
    }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return errorThrown;
    });
}
```

This will, in turn, allow appropriate actions to be taken on success/failure of the `open()` process.

```
open(id, nTr).then(function(rowNode) {
    //foo() returned a result and oTable.fnOpen() was called. 
}).fail(function(error) {
    //Something went wrong.
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Well, you didn't just answer my question but you also clarified me about the nature of the promises itself, and i hope this answer will be usefull to some other people, tested you solution and it worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @maikoORD, pleased to help. Thank you for your kind comments.